# Check if string contains character and number

Tags: c#

How do I check if a string contains the following characters "RM" followed by a any number or special character(-, _ etc) and then followed by "T"?

Ex: thisIsaString  ABRM21TC = yes, contains "RM" followed by a number and followed by "T"

Ex: thisIsaNotherString  RM-T = yes, contain "RM" followed by a special character then followed by "T"

Comment: You'd probably use a regular expression. Alternatively, you could check each character manually.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus That doesn't quite meet the criteria, but close. Read it again.

Comment: can u give me idea regarding that string matches regular expression?

Comment: Please define `special characters`. Which non-numeric characters do you wish to match?

Comment: Without a better definition of what `special characters` you want, maybe something like `RM(\d+|\W)T`? Although underscore is apparently considered a word character, so replace `\W` with whatever you set of acceptable special character is. For example: `RM(\d+|[-,_])T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp.

```
[^RM]*RM[^RMT]+T[^RMT]*
```

Here is a sample program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String rg = "[^RM]*RM[^RMT]+T[^RMT]*";
            string input = "111RM----T222";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, rg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine(match.Success);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your going to want to check the string using a regex (regular expression). See this MSDN for info on how to do that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx

Comment: No down vote, but I would have liked to see at the very least a sample expression included, as links have a terrible habit of going stale.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, "RM([^T]+)T");
```

- Check if the pattern is present by calling `match.Success`.
- Get the captured value by calling `match.Groups[1]`.

Here is a demo (on ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/16Xu51)):

```
foreach (var s in new[] {"ABRM21TC", "RM-T", "RxM-T", "ABR21TC"} ) {
    var match = Regex.Match(s, "RM([^T]+)T");
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' - {1} (Captures '{2}')", s, match.Success, match.Groups[1]);
}
```

It prints

```
'ABRM21TC' - True (Captures '21')
'RM-T' - True (Captures '-')
'RxM-T' - False (Captures '')
'ABR21TC' - False (Captures '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/learn-test-regular-expressions-with-the-regulator/

The Regulator is an advanced, free regular expressions testing and learning tool. It allows you to build and verify a regular expression against any text input, file or web, and displays matching, splitting or replacement results within an easy to understand, hierarchical tree.

Answer (score 1):

You should play around with more sample data especially regarding special characters, you can use [regexpal, I have added the two cases and an expression to get you started](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=RM%28%5B%5Cd%5C-_%5D%2a%29T&input=hisIsaString%20ABRM21TC%20=%20yes%0A%0A%0AthisIsaNotherString%20RM-T%20=%20yes).